# How to upgrade magento 1.8.0.1 to magento 1.9.0.1 version

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to upgrade my magento v1.8 to magento v1.9.I put backup of my files and database. then install a new magento v1.9 and replaced my 1.8 data to 1.9 as well as database tables also. But it is showing error and site is not at all opening and database tables are also not upgrading as well.

I am facing a lot of problems to upgrade magento 1.8 to 1.9. I checked all stuffs but didn't find any clue for upgrading 1.8 to 1.9.

If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: try this https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/1/Magento-Upgrade-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on running from a backup.. Did you drop all data from the tables before you run the restore?... If not it can cause a similar problem ?

There might also be database structure differences?.. between the 2 versions.. That would be extra mean by Magento tho.